# Can we create a contract and send it to multiple users using the DocuSign API

Tags: asp.net-core, docusignapi

We are working on an online registration web application using asp.net core. and we want to do these:-

1. We will upload a contract inside DocuSign and specify that users need to sign the contract.
2. inside our application, if the user complete the registration >> to inform docuSign to send the user an email to Sign the contract
3. We want the same contract inside DocuSign to be sent to multiple users, and each user will Sign his own contract.

Can anyone advice if this is supported by DocuSign API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is, there are, in fact, more than one way to do this.
But the gist of it is you want remote signing, not embedded signing.
In remote signing, an email is sent to each recipient to complete the envelope signing.
[Here is code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg002SigningViaEmailController.cs) for C# ASP.NET Core:

The gist of it is this:

```
// Create document objects, one per document
            Document doc1 = new Document();
            string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(document1(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName));
            doc1.DocumentBase64 = b64;
            doc1.Name = "Order acknowledgement"; // can be different from actual file name
            doc1.FileExtension = "html"; // Source data format. Signed docs are always pdf.
            doc1.DocumentId = "1"; // a label used to reference the doc
            Document doc2 = new Document {
                DocumentBase64 = doc2DocxBytes,
                Name = "Battle Plan", // can be different from actual file name
                FileExtension = "docx",
                DocumentId = "2"
            };
            Document doc3 = new Document
            {
                DocumentBase64 = doc3PdfBytes,
                Name = "Lorem Ipsum", // can be different from actual file name
                FileExtension = "pdf",
                DocumentId = "3"
            };
            // The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
            env.Documents =  new List<Document> { doc1, doc2, doc3};

            // create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
            // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
            Signer signer1 = new Signer {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name = signerName,
                RecipientId = "1",
                RoutingOrder = "1"
            };

            // routingOrder (lower means earlier) determines the order of deliveries
            // to the recipients. Parallel routing order is supported by using the
            // same integer as the order for two or more recipients.
```

This has 2 documents and notice RoutingOrder, which is used if you want more than one recipient and want to determine the order they sign.

I would recommend you clone the [entire repo](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp) and then see how it works, since it is an ASP.NET Core app you can run it from VS right away.

Hope this helps, happy to answer further questions.

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful reply, but where is the integration with DocuSign, i can see inside the code that they are creating documents, but where is the API integration with DocuSign.. sorry i am new to DocuSing..

Comment: no worries, I didn't paste the entire code. It is using what we call an SDK, which is a C# library that makes the actual API calls for you. You will still need to authenticate and get a token to make secure calls, but it makes it very simple. Please try to go to the GitHub repo I mentioned, read the instructions and try to get it working as a first step.

Comment: let me know how I else I can help. Once you are happy  - please mark the question as answered. thanks!

Comment: ok thanks, but going back to my first question, does the api support creating a general contract, which will be send to independent users to sign?, i mean each user will have his/her own contract? so i create a single document and send a copy to different users?? is this supported?

Comment: the eSignature API does not support document generation, per say. For example, you can't use the DocuSign API like you would a word processor. You can pass a file to the DocuSign API, along with various other properties. Now, this file can a PDF, html, png, etc. Our platform will then handle all of the interactions required to fulfill that contract.

Comment: yup, Matt is correct, I would also really suggest you try the code example, see how it works and then you can change it to your needs. You can create your document on the fly using other libraries and then send it to the DocuSign API for example. But you will understand better how DocuSign works once you used it for a bit.

Comment: @testtest anything else you need?